# column update in sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains 3 columns as below:

```
col1 col2 col3   
---- ---- ----
1     1   null
2     2   null
3     3   null
4     1   null
5     1   null
6     1   null
7     2   null
ETC
```

I need to update a third column in the same table as follows:

```
col1 col2 col3
---- ---- ----
1     1     1
2     2     1
3     3     1
4     1     2
5     1     3
6     1     4
7     2     4
```

The logic behind the update is that each time the 2nd column contains a 1 in it, the third has to increment. The first column is just a sequential integer column.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind the numbers in the third column?

Comment: Each time the 2nd column contains a 1 in it, the third has to increment, The first column is just a sequential integer column

Comment: How large is your table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the row_number analytical function to number the rows with col2 = 1 sequentially and then use a subquery to find to closest value with a lower col1 for the other rows.

So given a test table like this:

```
create table t (c1 int, c2 int, c3 int);
insert t (c1, c2) values 
(1, 1),
(2, 2),
(3, 3),
(4, 1),
(5, 1),
(6, 1),
(7, 2);
```

A query like this:

```
;with cte as (
    select t.c1, t.c2, x.c3 
    from t
    left join (
       select c1, c2, row_number() over (partition by c2 order by c1) c3 
       from t
       where c2 = 1 
    ) x on t.c1 = x.c1
)

update t 
set t.c3 = coalesce(cte1.c3,(select max(cte2.c3) from cte cte2 where cte2.c1 < cte1.c1))
from cte cte1
where t.c1 = cte1.c1
```

Will give the following result:

```
c1  c2  c3
1   1   1
2   2   1
3   3   1
4   1   2
5   1   3
6   1   4
7   2   4
```

Another, possibly faster, way to do this would be:

```
update t1 set c3 = (select count(*) from t where c2 = 1 and c1 <= t1.c1) from t t1
```